# How to branch out from master in Azure DevOps automatically

Tags: git, azure-devops, branch, azure-pipelines

I have a master branch. I need to schedule it to branch out once per week. As my research, there is no such that automation feature in Azure DevOps.

I would like to know if it's possible to do. Do we need to create a tool for it?

Comment: If Shayki 's answer is helpful ,can you accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a branch with build pipeline and set the build to be scheduled:

[image]

You must "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" for the above script (in the agent job options):

[image]

Triggers tab:

[image]

**Note: you need a new branch name each time, so maybe you need to use a variable that increment each build (like build number) for the branch name.**